# How can I set a timeout for ExecuteAsync of BackgroundService?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a BackgroundService called Worker, which I override the ExecuteAsync method to run something each 10 seconds. Sometimes, what I run lasts very long. In this scenario, I want to kill what I am running, then rerun it. How can I achieve this?

My BackgroundService is as follows:

```
    public class Worker : BackgroundService {
        private readonly ITask task;
        private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime appLifeTime;

        public Worker(ITask task, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifeTime) {
            this.task = task;
            this.appLifeTime = appLifeTime;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try {
                    this.task.Execute(stoppingToken);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    this.appLifeTime.StopApplication();
                }

                await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface ITask {
        void Execute(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
    }
```

Comment: Pass a CancellationToken that cancels after X amount of time. Combine it with the host's stopping token. Check which token was cancelled and either stop the app or retry. Only obviously works if your task actually respects the token...

Comment: CancellationTokenSource has CancelAfter() method.

Comment: Execute really needs to return a Task you can await and not void IMO. Things become easier

Answer (score 2):

You could do something along these lines:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
    var cancellationSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(stoppingToken);
    cancellationSource.CancelAfter(10000);
    
    return Task.Run(() => task.Execute(cancellationSource.Token));
}
```

If you want to handle execptions and/or await the task then you can but this is a simple example.

Comment: This won't stop the main task though. It will still carry on processing since it's not told to cancel

Comment: You are correct sorry, I oversimplified. I edited the answer

Comment: Also, I think it would be nicer if the `ITask.Execute` method returned a `Task`

Comment: Oops missed the void in the method signature... But **now** neither task will stop if the host stops

Comment: One could use `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource` to link the cancellation tokens if needed. I'd rather not give too many specifics here as it really depends on the user's case.

Comment: Perhaps it would be sufficient to set a timeout on the `cancellationSource`, combine it with the given `stoppingToken` and avoid the `Task.Delay` altogether.

Comment: I simplified things with the things mentioned above. This should work but I did not test it.
Also, again, the `Task.Run` could be avoided if the `ITask.Execute` method returned a `Task`.